# Jmeter- how to find the time taken for the report to generate

Tags: jmeter

how to check the time taken for some report to generate using jmeter

In my application we need to submit report and check for the time taken for the report to be completed. it usually takes about 15-20 minutes. How to check that using jmeter.

I checked in Listener- View results in table , aggregate report - it doesn't have that info. Kindly help

Comment: In aggregate report or summary report for each request, it shows time taken by that request to complete(min,avg,max time). check time for your report generation request that is your required output, though it is (server processing time for report generation + network latency). If you are ok with latency(test application in LAN) then you will get 99% approx time for report generation.

Comment: @Nachiket- The https requests are available only till clicking the submit button in the application. After clicking submit button , application runs and get the generated report in few minutes, i couldnt find the request for the report generation. Any help on this will be very helpful, awaiting for your reply

Comment: If report generation functionality starts after clicking submit then that is request you are looking for. if that shows that time in min then it means that is report generation time + latency. As  I said if you testing in lan then you can ignore latency and consider that time as report generation functionality time. Jmeter is load generation tool so you cant get actual server CPU time on application server, for this you need to add loggers to your code or use profilers if you don't have source code to get cpu time taken by report generation functionality.

Comment: If time is in min (valid for ETL/DW, invalid for general web apps.) then probably tune it and test it again to see difference

Comment: After clicking submit button, all the operations takes place in backend db and we get a mail of the generated report and status update in UI i,e status(started, completed). submit button request gets us the time taken for just clicking the button not the entire report generation time. As the operations happens in backend db, unable to get the time taken for the report generation. is there any way of getting it.

Comment: Is there any possible chance of monitoring the report status in UI (start, complete) and calculate the time taken by (completed status time - start time). One more drawback here is we need to refresh the UI to check if there is any change in status, UI does not prompt immediately when status changes, we need to refresh the UI to check

Comment: I assume you you can see start time for report and end time also once it completes the report generation, just you have to refresh the table/UI to check it. In such cases you can keep a loop in jmeter for that request to continue till it completes the report generation activity, like loop around refresh request checking/refreshing every 2 sec and If controller to check status of report generation.

Answer (score 0):

In Jmeter you can use below logic to check for completion time of report generation activity.
and your report generation activity has columns similar to,

[image]

Which has start time and end time (from which you can get approx time for your report generation activity, this raises question if you see this through UI why are you saying, you cant find out execution time for report.)
If you want it in Jmeter load testing then probably you have a custom code(beanshell postprocessor) extracting both values from result and logging it into log file.

status check workflow would be somewhat like,

[image]

While controller ------- to loop continuously till our condition satisfied (my mistake,   value should be status!=complete)

http request     ---- Refresh reqeust

Constant time    ---- delay of 2 seconds